# Alternative to Internet Explorer/ActiveX for creating a username/password prompt popup?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, activex

For several years now, I've been using the Javascript function below to have Internet Explorer generate a username and password prompt by using ActiveX.  Now that Internet Explorer is about to be retired, does anyone know how I can accomplish the same thing using Edge, which doesn't support ActiveX (or by using Firefox or Chrome or...)?  Thanks to all who respond.

```
function PasswordBox( strIETitle ) {
    objIE = new ActiveXObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" );
    objIE.FullScreen = False;
    objIE.AddressBar = False;
    objIE.MenuBar = False;
    objIE.StatusBar = False;
    objIE.ToolBar = False;
    objIE.RegisterAsDropTarget = False;
    objIE.Navigate("about:blank");
    strLoginID = strLocalUser;

    do {
        WScript.Sleep( 100 );
    } while ( ! objIE.ReadyState == 4 );

    objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 200 + 70 );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.moveTo(
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.width / 2 - 200,
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.height / 2 - 200 );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<html>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<title>" + strIETitle + "</title>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "<style type='text/css'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<!--" );
    objIE.document.writeln( ".fixed { font-family:courier new, monospace }" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "-->" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</style>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "</head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<body bgcolor=Silver>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<form>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<b>" + strIETitle + "</b><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<tr><td colspan=2 align=left>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Enter your username and password:<br>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Username:&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input id='userid' size=20 class='fixed' " +
        "value='" + strLoginID + "'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Password:&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='password' id='passwd' size=20 class='fixed'><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='button' value='Submit' id='but0' " +
        "onclick=\"submitted.value='DONE';\">" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='hidden' id='submitted' value=''>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</form>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</body>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</html>" );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.scroll="no";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderStyle = "outset";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderWidth = "3px";
    objIE.Visible = True;
    objIE.document.addEventListener( "keydown", keyHit, false );

    objWShell.AppActivate( strIETitle );
    objIE.document.getElementById( "passwd" ).focus();
    blnPwdBoxWait = '';
    try {
        do {
            WScript.Sleep( 100 );
            if ( objIE.Visible && blnPwdBoxWait == '' ) {
                blnPwdBoxWait = objIE.document.getElementById( "submitted" ).value;
            }
        } while ( blnPwdBoxWait == '' );
    } catch( err ) {
        WScript.Echo('ERROR: ' + err.message);
        blnPwdBoxWait = 'DONE';
    }
    strLoginID = objIE.document.getElementById( "userid" ).value;
    strPassword = objIE.document.getElementById( "passwd" ).value;
    objIE.Visible = False;
    objIE.Quit();
    objIE = null;

    return strPassword;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you do not want to build something from scratch you need to search for html/javascript modal dialog. An example of one (with code) is at the w3.com site at https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html

Comment: I think you have two choices. One is loading the site in [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) in Edge. IE mode in Edge supports ActiveX controls. Second is changing your code to JavaScript without ActiveX. Just like the comment above, you can use Modal Dialog to show the username and password prompt.

Comment: Mifo - thanks for the suggestion, but since my function uses "writeln" commands to create the HTML code that IE is reading, it isn't clear to me how modal would parse the commands, not to mention the code that formats the IE window being opened.

Comment: Yu Zhou - thanks for the idea, but since IE is being invoked by the "objIE = new ActiveXObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )" command, it isn't clear to me how I could change that command to invoke Edge in IE mode.

Comment: IE mode supports ActiveX controls. You only need to load the website executing the JavaScript function in IE mode, then the ActiveX controls can run and the newly generated page will open in IE.

Comment: Yu Zhow - I see what you're saying, but wouldn't that require having the HTML in a separate file, so that I can specify the separate file when I run Edge in IE mode?  I do like the fact that my function is totally self-contained.  Is there a way to run Edge such that it reads the HTML from within the function, rather than from an external file?

Comment: I just wanted to update/close this question by pointing to my follow-up question, which resolved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018939/how-get-variables-to-and-from-hta-called-from-vbscript/.  Thanks again to Mifo and Yu Zhow for their comments and suggestions.